# is committing major sin?

Tags: game

I play a game named valorant .In this game ,when the opponent kill me there creates some kinds of animations such as when he kill me,my character suddenly fall on his feet and his head slightly bow down but not completely.by watching a video ,you can take a clear idea about my words. here is the video link of the animation : https://youtu.be/A3cSuJZMN4o

now my question is: Am i committing shirk or major sin by playing this game??? though my intention is not to do that

plz kindly watch the video and answer my question . I am very tensed.

Answer (score 0):

**Long answer**

What is bowing towards the feet of the other character IS NOT YOU, but a virtual character created and animated by the game. So in my opinion, YOU are not committing Shirk, your character whenever you lose the game does that by intentional programming. So you are not Sinful for that, It is something that is 1, was not a part of your intention, 2 wasn't even done by you.

**Short Answer**

You did not commit shirk.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).